# ChartJS and DiscordJS implementation question

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js, discord.js

Is there a way to go about using data from discord.js in a ChartJS scenario?

I toyed with the idea of using dynamic updates to graph activity. Though i didn't quite get the idea down to where i wanted it to be.

Any tips on how to start this or a general direction?

Comment: thank you! that was practically what i was looking for. Is there a way to push live visualization through the discord web package? Counting per-say?

Comment: @Androz2091 can you update the link it seems broken

Comment: Sure, https://github.com/manage-invite/manage-invite-bot/blob/master/commands/core/stats.js

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Androz2091](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11856499/androz2091) comment:

I used [ChartJS Canva Node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-node-canvas) to render to [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) graph as picture which will be used to create [Discord.MessageAttachment](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment) object. Then I reply with a  [MessageEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) to server.

The following gist should represent the previous workflow: [ChartJs - DiscordJs - Node Canva](https://gist.github.com/BlueSkunka/f248ffa668fcaf6700efd28e69a33ce3)

I used this code in my first discord bot and it's working well, here the bot response look like:
[image: A bit messy to see what's going on but my bot is still in progress ^^]

A bit messy to see what's going on but my bot is still in progress ^^

Hope this will be usefull in the future, feel free to ask for more informations.

Comment: ChartJS Canva node is a life saver for my project! Thank you!